# Keep content loaded visible after scroll-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am quite new to Javascript and what I am trying to achieve is to load AJAX some JS content only when the page scroll reaches a certain point (the div #point). Everything works fine, my content is loaded when the div #point is reached, but here there is a problem: I want my loaded content to STAY when the user scrolls back up, I do not want to disappear again. Could you please suggest me a way to achieve that?

And a second question: how can I add an offset in order to activate .load a bunch of pixels before pagescroll gets near the #point div?

Here is the code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var s = $("#point");
     var pos = s.position();                   
     $(window).scroll(function() {
         var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
         if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
           $("#point").load("MYCONTENT.PHP");
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="point">
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean to check if the point has been reached:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var reached = false;
        var loaded = false;
        var s = $("#point");
        var pos = s.position() - 10 ; //Additional pixels you mentioned.                 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
                 reached = true; 
            }
           if(reached && !loaded){
              $("#point").load("MYCONTENT.PHP");
              loaded=true;
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="point">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There is one more problem: I noticed that MYCONTENT gets loaded EVERYTIME page position changes (every time user scrolls). Since it is a multimedial file, it is annoying. How can I make .load being executed just one time?

Comment: @gentletechie See my edit. I added a boolean to check if it has been loaded already.